# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error while inserting data through cursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a simple `cursor` which fetches the data and inserts the data based on the conditions into 2 tables. Now for valid conditions I am getting the below error. Please guide me how to check and match the conditions.

The error is below

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
>   ORA-06512: at "APP_FIBERINV.FIP_VAL_INV_DATA", line 37

And below is the cursor.

```html
create or replace PROCEDURE FIP_VAL_INV_DATA AS 
l_state_name r4g_lb.mantainenceboundary_evw.jiostatename%type;
l_maint_zone_code r4g_lb.mantainenceboundary_evw.maintenancezonecode%type;

begin

  for cur_r in (select rj_span_id, 
                       rj_maintenance_zone_name,
                       rj_maintenance_zone_code,
                       rj_state_name,
                       rj_network_category,
                       rj_network_type,
                       rj_construction_methodology,
                       inventory_status_code,
                       rj_route_name,
                       rj_intracity_link_id,
                       calculated_length 
                      from app_fttx.transmedia@sat   
                      where rownum < 100
               )
               
  loop         
    select max(jiostatename) 
      into l_state_name
      from r4g_lb.mantainenceboundary_evw
      where jiostatename = cur_r.rj_state_name
      and rownum = 1;

      select max(maintenancezonecode) 
      into l_maint_zone_code
      from r4g_lb.mantainenceboundary_evw
      where maintenancezonecode = cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_code
      and rownum = 1;
   
       if length(cur_r.rj_span_id) = '21'        
     --  if cur_r.rj_span_id > '0'        
          and l_state_name = 1
          and cur_r.inventory_status_code = 'IPL'
          and regexp_like(cur_r.rj_span_id, 'SP(N|Q|R|S).*_(BU|MP)$')
          and l_maint_zone_code = 1
          
    then       
       INSERT INTO tbl_fiber_valid_trans_data 
         (span_id, maintenance_zone_name, maintenance_zone_code, r4g_state_name, inventory_status_code)
          values 
         (cur_r.rj_span_id, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_name, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_code, cur_r.rj_state_name, cur_r.inventory_status_code);
    else
        INSERT INTO TBL_FIBER_INVALID_TRANS_DATA 
          (span_id, maintenance_zone_name, maintenance_zone_code, r4g_state_name, inventory_status_code)
           values 
          (cur_r.rj_span_id, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_name, cur_r.rj_maintenance_zone_code, cur_r.rj_state_name, cur_r.inventory_status_code);
    end if;       
  end loop;  
END FIP_VAL_INV_DATA;
```

**UPDATE**

Data structure of the table `tbl_fiber_valid_trans_data`

```html
Name                     Null Type           
------------------------ ---- -------------- 
SPAN_ID                       NVARCHAR2(100) 
MAINTENANCE_ZONE_NAME         NVARCHAR2(100) 
MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE         NVARCHAR2(50)  
R4G_STATE_NAME                NVARCHAR2(50)  
STATE_NAME                    NVARCHAR2(50)  
NETWORK_CATEGORY              NVARCHAR2(100) 
NETWORK_TYPE                  NVARCHAR2(100) 
CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY      NVARCHAR2(50)  
INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE         NVARCHAR2(20)  
OWNERSHIP_TYPE_CODE           NVARCHAR2(20)  
ROUTE_NAME                    NVARCHAR2(100) 
INTRACITY_LINK_ID             NVARCHAR2(100) 
CALCULATED_LENGTH             NUMBER(38,8)   
LAST_UPDATED_BY               NVARCHAR2(100) 
LAST_UPDATED_DATE             DATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your columns data type it is a bit hard to guess the real error but I think it comes from the `and l_state_name = 1` criteria because `l_state_name` must be a varchar and as you compare it to `1`, the engine tries to cast `l_state_name` to a number

Fix with `and l_state_name = '1'`

It must be the same with `and l_maint_zone_code = 1` => `and l_maint_zone_code = '1'`

By the way change also `length(cur_r.rj_span_id) = '21'` to `length(cur_r.rj_span_id) = 21`

Comment: but the rownum = 1 which seems to be number, wont validate it properly. right ? still i am checking. Also updated the table structure

Comment: tried with the above changes which you gave, but even the valid records are going inside the invalid table.. can u help on this

Comment: yes the error message was fixed, but logic was still not achieved

Comment: You should accept the answer as it solves the issue you opened the post for. About the logic it depends on your data. Maybe your regex is wrong. You should use ```dbms_output.put_line``` to output your variables and debug

Comment: sure, if this gives you satisfaction sure I will accept it and upvote too.THANKS

Comment: It's not for me. It's just for the other people who meet the issue and look for a valid answer ;)